# Python List comprehension PCEP questions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I recently came across a list comprehension questions in practice exams and although I have the correct answer I don't understand how those answers are valid.
Question: How many stars (*) will the following snippet send to the console?

```
lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
   for x in lst:
      for y in x:
         if y < 2:
            print('*', end='')
```

My answer was 2 stars. My thinking is that lst = [0,1,2]. x and lst should be the same number of elements - 0,1,2. Only 0, 1 are <2, fulfilling the condition. However, the answer is 3. I've verified on python tutor that the list = [0,0,1]. But I dont understand why. Can someone please explain?

Comment: The correct answer is zero...this code will produce an `IndentationError`...but seriously the best way to understand these things is to print the various parts. Try adding a `print(x)` after `for x in lst:`. Or print `lst` where you will discover it is *not* `[0,1,2]`.

Comment: thank you, apologies for the indentation error - saw it after i posted, but good to point it out for others.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]**:

First iteration:

```
r = 0 => range(0) -> doesn't print anything
```

Second iteration:

```
r = 1 => range(1) -> 0 -> prints * once
```

Third iteration

```
r = 2 => range(2) -> 0,1 -> prints * twice
```

Comment: aaah, this actually helped me a great deal. I understand now its the output of one feeds into the other - so for each value of r, you then get the range of the at value for the values of c, which in turn gives the lst.
much appreciated sir!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it will print "***" star .One star in second iteration and two star in third iteration.